# ios test macro errors "Expected identefier"

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, ipa

I'm trying to create a simple test macro but I'm having errors in the following lines. ANy of you knows why or how I can I fix them?

```
#define test(condition) do{\
    if (condition)
    {\        //// <-----Expected identifier or (
        NSlog @"passed: " %@ #condtion); \

    }
    else
    {\
        NSLog(@"failed: " @ #condition); \

    }
}   //// <-----extraneous closing brace ( "}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a backslash at the end of every line of your multi-line macro (except the last).

```
#define test(condition) do{\
    if (condition) \
    {\
        NSlog @"passed: " %@ #condtion); \
    } \
    else \
    { \
        NSLog(@"failed: " @ #condition); \
    } \
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify that quite a bit. Here:

```
#define test(condition) NSLog("%s: %s\n", condition ? "Passed" : "Failed", #condition);
```

Call like:

```
int i = 6;
test(i > 8);
test(i < 8);
```

Output:

```
Failed: i > 8
Passed: i < 8
```